# JavaScript how to set member variable from a callback function?

Tags: javascript

I have a custom object that needs to do some async loading of a file in a the background using XMLHttpRequest.

I have setup the request and invoke it properly, get a response to the proper method defined in the prototype of the object. But I believe that this object is not an "instance" of the correct object. For example:

Call member function on Obj A.
Function executes and starts an XMLHttpRequest.
The XMLHttpRequest calls the onload function properly.
Inside the onload function that was set, I change a property of Obj A. (Just a boolean if your wondering.)
This is where the issue is happening, the boolean doesn't actually change to what is expected. Is there a work around for this?

Edit (Code Snippet Added):

```
/******************************************/
/* Callback to process the vertex shader. */
/******************************************/
Entity.prototype.onRecieveVertexShader = function(e)
{
    console.log("RECEIVED VERTEX SHADER");
    this.vertexShaderHandle = GL.createShader(GL.VERTEX_SHADER);
    GL.shaderSource(this.vertexShaderHandle, e.target.response);
    GL.compileShader(this.vertexShaderHandle);

    // This doesn't work.
    this.vertexShaderCompiled = true;
}

/********************************************/
/* Callback to process the fragment shader. */
/********************************************/
Entity.prototype.onRecieveFragmentShader = function(e)
{
    console.log("RECIEVED FRAGMENT SHADER");
    this.fragmentShaderHandle = GL.createShader(GL.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GL.shaderSource(this.fragmentShaderHandle, e.target.response);
    GL.compileShader(this.fragmentShaderHandle);

    // This doesn't work.
    this.fragmentShaderCompiled = true;
}

Entity.prototype.getAndCompileVertexShader = function(filename)
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "shaders/" + filename, true);
    request.responseType = "text";
    request.onload = this.onRecieveVertexShader;
    request.send();
}

Entity.prototype.getAndCompileFragmentShader = function(filename)
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "shaders/" + filename, true);
    request.responseType = "text";
    request.onload = this.onRecieveFragmentShader;
    request.send();
}
```

The first two functions are the call backs that are "improperly" working. The second two are called from the "main thread". These start the HTTP Requests.

(Adding the code that calls these functions.)

```
function Custom3DObject(verts, indexes, normals)
{   
    Entity.call(this);

    this.vertices = verts;
    this.normals = normals;
    this.indices = indexes;

    console.log("CUSTOM 3D OBJECT USING: " + this.vertices.length / 3 + " VERTICES.");
    console.log("CUSTOM 3D OBJECT USING: " + this.normals.length / 3 + " NORMALS.");
    console.log("CUSTOM 3D OBJECT USING: " + this.indices.length + " INDICES.");

    this.WMatrix = mat4.create(); // Identity for now.
    this.VMatrix = mat4.lookAt([], [0, 0, -5], [0, 0, 1], [0, -1, 0]);
    this.PMatrix = mat4.perspective([], 45, 1280 / 720, 1, 20000);
    this.WVPMatrix = mat4.multiply([], this.VMatrix, this.WMatrix);
    this.WVPMatrix = mat4.multiply([], this.PMatrix, this.WVPMatrix);

    this.getAndCompileVertexShader("test_vertex_shader.vs");
    this.getAndCompileFragmentShader("test_fragment_shader.ps");
}
```

And the code that constructs this object is:

```
this.entityArray.push(new Custom3DObject(sphere.verts, sphere.inds, sphere.norms));
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code

Comment: It would be easier to follow your thoughts with some code...

Comment: Added the code snippet.

Comment: Where is the code where you call the "class"?

Comment: Added the code that constructs the class, and calls the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=243142&sid=d65b4924ba3b506ab0938886497f5272

Basically, before defining / setting my call back function "onload", it says to define a variable, var local = this; first. So my function now looks like this:

```
Entity.prototype.getAndCompileVertexShader = function(filename)
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "shaders/" + filename, true);
    request.responseType = "text";

    var local = this;

    request.onload = function(e) {

        console.log("RECEIVED VERTEX SHADER");
        local.vertexShaderHandle = GL.createShader(GL.VERTEX_SHADER);
        GL.shaderSource(local.vertexShaderHandle, e.target.response);
        GL.compileShader(local.vertexShaderHandle);

        local.vertexShaderCompiled = true;

    }
    request.send();
}
```

And use that new variable in the call back function to access member (instance) data. Weird.